# Pine Script Colour Input

Tags: pine-script

using below code in pine script, the style input is Color 0 and Color 1. How do I change the name of Color 0 to "Bull Candle" and Color 1 to "Bear Candle"?

```
plotcandle(open, high, low, close, title='candle', color=(open < close) ? green : red, wickcolor=gray)
```

[Image attached for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xn7pd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Modifying title of inputs on Style tab is unavailable. Instead of you can use input type color with defined title, like this:

```
//@version=4
study("Input colors")
c1 = input(type=input.color, defval = color.green, title="Bull Candle")
c2 = input(type=input.color, defval = color.red, title="Bear Candle")
plotcandle(open, high, low, close, title='candle', color=(open < close) ? c1 : c2, wickcolor=color.gray)
```

Comment: The above code opens a sub window on the chart. However when I add this code in existing program, I am getting error. //@version=1

study(title="Stock Market" , overlay=true)

c1 = input(type=input.color, defval = color.green, title="Bull Candle")
c2 = input(type=input.color, defval = color.red, title="Bear Candle")
plotcandle(open, high, low, close, title='candle', color=(open < close) ? c1 : c2, wickcolor=color.gray)


len = input(5, minval=1, title="EMA_1")
src = input(close, title="Source")
out = ema(src, len)
plot(out, color=red,linewidth=1, title="EMA_1", transp=0)

Comment: To prevent open subwindow on chart add param overlay=true to call of `study(...)`function, for example: 

`study("Input colors", overlay=true)`

Speaking about the second problem, I recommend you to use `//@version=4` of PineScript, because your script using so old `//@version=1`, which not maintain this features